# A simpler way of finding the start of the week for any start day

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, optimization

We need to find the start of the week (a datetime), given these two variables:

1. `now` - the current datetime
2. `START_DAY` - the day of the week (0-6, where 0 is monday and 6 is sunday) that we consider the "start of the week"

We can use looping, but this seems like too many steps for a simple problem:

```
week_start = datetime(now.year, now.month, now.day)
while week_start.weekday() != START_DAY:
    week_start = week_start - timedelta(days=1)
```

It's really easy if `START_DAY` is always `0` (monday):

```
week_start = datetime(now.year, now.month, now.day) - timedelta(days=now.weekday())
```

Or always `6` (sunday):

```
week_start = datetime(now.year, now.month, now.day) - timedelta(days=(0 if now.weekday() == START_DAY else now.weekday() + 1))
```

What is a simple method for calculating the start of the week for any value of `START_DAY`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of days between `START_DAY` and `now` is `now.weekday() - START_DAY`. However, if today is before `START_DAY` (e.g. if today is Wednesday and `START_DATE` is 6 = Sunday), that number will be negative, and subtracting it from today would give you a date in the future.

Since you probably don't want that, you need the difference modulo 7:

```
week_start = now.date() - timedelta(days=(now.weekday() - START_DAY) % 7)
```

Examples:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> now = datetime(2017, 2, 1)
>>> print(now.strftime("%d/%m/%y (%a)"))
01/02/17 (Wed)
>>> for START_DAY in range(7):
...     start_week = now.date() - timedelta(days=(now.weekday() - START_DAY) % 7)
...     print(start_week.strftime("%d/%m/%y (%a)"))
... 
30/01/17 (Mon)
31/01/17 (Tue)
01/02/17 (Wed)
26/01/17 (Thu)
27/01/17 (Fri)
28/01/17 (Sat)
29/01/17 (Sun)
```